# Counting values (countif) on entire columns based on their values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that takes the responses of a Form.

It has two sheets: The **Form Responses 1** which contains the responses and the sheet **Report** which I've created to a) extract the data from the responses and b) format the table.

The sheet **Report** has two columns: **A**) the questions and **B**) the counts of the response **Always**.

The function I'm using in **B2** is:

```
=COUNTIF('Form Responses 1'!$G:$G,"Always")
```

What is the easiest way to do something like auto-fill to have this function running for all questions while changing the column only, so the cells of column **B** will have:

```
B3  -->     =COUNTIF('Form Responses 1'!$H:$H,"Always")
B4  -->     =COUNTIF('Form Responses 1'!$I:$I,"Always")
B5  -->     =COUNTIF('Form Responses 1'!$J:$J,"Always")
….
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this formula work as you want:

`=COUNTIF(FILTER('Form Responses 1'!A:Z,'Form Responses 1'!1:1=A2),"Always")`

Answer (score 3):

In B2 use,

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX('Form Responses 1'!$A:$ZZ, 0, ROW(7:7)),"Always")
```

Fill down.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't clarify the question.
I want to search for the column depending on its content.
So, the function in B2 will pass the content of A2 and looks for the column containing that title, say it's G:G; then it'll count the **Always** occurrences.
This'll guarantee that even if the position of the response in **Form Responses 1** has been changed; the function will reflect the corresponding count.

Comment: So you named the column header label in row 1 `"G:G"` regardless of where it actually resides on the worksheet. Brilliant!

Comment: No, the label of the first row in column `G` is the question which I want the function in the report sheet to search for.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking Countif(Index(Match( which would be like this:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX('Form Responses 1'!$A:$HZ,0,MATCH(A2,'Form Responses 1'!$1:$1,0)),"Always")
```

So it will find A2 if it is a header in `'Form Responses 1'!$1:$1` and then get the count of "Always" in that column.

Comment: This one works, but the FILTER arguments need to be ordered correctly:
`=COUNTIF(INDEX('Form Responses 1'!$A:$HZ,0,MATCH(A2,'Form Responses 1'!$1:$1,0)),"Always")`

Comment: errr, `INDEX` arguments

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`indirect()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) function. Specifically

```
=countif(indirect("sheet2!c"&row()+5,false),"Always")
```

where `row()` returns current row number. So if we are at the second row, we have `indirect("sheet2!c7",false)`, which means the entire 7th column in sheet2, or sheet2!G:G

See [full example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T63hDPVnKZvpon6iYAX7fIns1alv-PWggsq9XMB1bGA/edit?usp=sharing)

Psst... do you know there is webapps.stackexchange.com for all Google Drive questions?